# How to return an image from a Custom Function in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to create a custom function that returns an image to the cell that calls it.

Here's a simplified version of my script.

```
function ProfilePic() {
  var profilepicurl = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  cell.setFormula('=IMAGE("' + profilepicurl + '")');
}
```

This script will give me a permission error because custom functions are not supposed to return formulas (with setFormula()).

Is there any other way to return an image to the cell that calls a function like this one?

Comment: Have you tired doing it the other way around? Return a url with you custom function which is wrapped inside a image Function, like so: =image(profilepic())

Comment: In your code `getActiveCell()` always returns `a1` which I don't know why. For example `var cell = sheet.getRange('d2');` yields the desired result.

Comment: @JagannathanAlagurajan Spot on! So simple and great solution. Thank you!